# UNC Path machine

Tags: c#, network-programming, unc

This code work with me in form of my project but I must access credential of shared server in network map before.

I want to add some code with credential of remote server access without put username and password in network map just add in my code.

### to save images in UNC path machine

This is part of my code:

```
public bool OnPostTransfer(Bitmap bit)
{
    m_ImageCore.IO.LoadImage(bit);

    string fil_name = "new_f.jpg";

    string d_path = "//WIN-KCA4SC9E2U4/Users/hosam/embs/" + fil_name;

    string n_path = pf.check_exist(d_path);
    bit.Save(n_path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    bit.Dispose();

    int x = gv_image.Rows.Count;
    gv_image.Rows.Add();
    Image img = Image.FromFile(n_path);
    gv_image.Rows[x].Cells[3].Value = img;
    gv_image.Rows[x].Cells[4].Value = n_path;
    gv_image.Rows[x].Cells[5].Value = "0";

    //  MessageBox.Show("Image acquired successfully. \r\n");
    return true;
}
```

note: the remote server and my pc is in same workgroup in network

Comment: So, you want answer in c# or vb.net?

Comment: as my code c# please